# how to do the transition of rectangle width change?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt4

lets just say theoreticaly, that I have

```
Rectangle {
    id: testRect
    width: 100
}
```

and once i start the timer with interval tick 50ms, it should just extend the width of Rect:

```
Timer {
    id: testTimer
    interval: 50
    onTriggered: testRect.width += 50
}
```

which works fine, but even when its onlz 50ms, its still seems to be quite not smooth transition.

Any idea how to smoothen the width change?

Please note this is only for learning purposes, what I will learn here will use in different situations, therefore please dont ask what is the puspose of the code...

Thank you!

Comment: Using timer for this purpose looks not so good idea. Use State, Transition etc. for that, let QtQuick do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rely on the animation features available in QtQuick to animate property changes.

In your case, you can define different states, with transitions between states where you define how an item should behave when going from one state to another. (See relevant [documentation about states](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-states.html))

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.margins: 100
        height: 200
        color: "red"

        state: "default"

        states: [
            State {
                name: "default"

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    width: 200
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "bigger"

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    width: 250
                }
            }
        ]

        transitions: Transition {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 500 //ms
                target: rect
                properties: "width"
            }
        }

        // Just there to trigger the state change by clicking on the Rectangle
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                if (rect.state === "default")
                    rect.state = "bigger"
                else
                    rect.state = "default"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can define a [behavior](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html), which is more simple to define when you only act on a single property:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.margins: 100
        height: 200
        width: 200
        color: "red"


        Behavior on width {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 500 //ms
            }
        }

        // Just there to trigger the width change by clicking on the Rectangle
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                if (rect.width === 200)
                    rect.width = 250
                else
                    rect.width = 200
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if you really want a smooth animation, you can use SmoothedAnimation instead of NumberAnimation (which is a linear animation by default)